# Gparted Unable to Resize

Tags: 16.04, gparted

I have dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu) initially I had allocated 30GB for Ubuntu. Now I want to increase the size with unallocated space. But when I try do that using Gparted the resize is not showing the unallocated space.

[image]

Comment: Did you just make space ? Are there unapplied changes ?

Comment: Try the resize from a live media/installer.  You are trying to resize the locked root, and gparted cannot do what you want.  In some cases, adding to the end of a running root may be possible, you are trying to add to the beginning.

Comment: Since you are growing to the front, you cannot do it while mounted.

Comment: live media/installer need to download it? @ubfan1

Comment: @ubfan1 good catch. Yes you need to run from a live media (usb) to resize the root partition.

Comment: @ubfan1 You have any guide how to do it. Like youtube video or blog post?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0czAJwEbtFs

Answer (score 2):

You can't move/resize /dev/sda9 because it's a live mounted/running system. You must boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Here's how...

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** the /dev/sda9 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda9 all the way right
- click on the `Accept` icon to do the work
- reboot the system